# How to check a popup menu item?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, menu

How to check a popup menu item?

Answer (score 4):

using [CMenu::CheckMenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbd652b3(VS.80).aspx)

See the example in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z8dxz39(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

In case of context menu, use MF_CHECKED style when you add items to menu using AppendMenu() function.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a popup menu entry there is no command number and you can only use **MF_BYPOSITION** parameter.

For example if you have menu created with

```
HMenu = CreateMenu();
```

And a Menu entry "Edition" where you have "Select..." with 3 choices :

```
HPopSubMenuSelect = CreatePopupMenu();
AppendMenu(HPopSubMenuSelect, MF_STRING, 20, "All");
AppendMenu(HPopSubMenuSelect, MF_STRING, 21, "Word");
AppendMenu(HPopSubMenuSelect, MF_STRING, 22, "Nothing");
HPopMenuEdition = CreatePopupMenu();
AppendMenu(HPopMenuEdition, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP , HPopSubMenuSelect,"Select...");
AppendMenu(HMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP , HPopMenuEdition, "Edition");
```

Then to check this you must call

```
CheckMenuItem(HPopMenuEdition, 1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_CHECKED);
// Or for uncheck
// CheckMenuItem(HPopMenuEdition, 1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_UNCHECKED);
```

Greetings.